# How to convert string to char * in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I convert a `string` in to `char *` I was using the following method, but it doesn't work.

At runtime it gives me the following error:

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'url' is being used without
>   being initialized.

eventhough I have initialized it as shown in the code bellow. Can you please show me with an example?

```
    char* url;
    sup = "news"
    sup="http://www."+sup+"yahoo.com";
    strcpy(url, sup.c_str());
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, C++ in console

Comment: if you just want to use the character pointer you could simply use sup.c_str() instead of allocating equal number of bytes for the variable 'url' again.

Comment: @Unni it would be a const char* though (not just a char*). But I agree that may be what's actually required.

Comment: I would use `std::string` everywhere, until you needed to pass it to a legacy system. Then use `std::string::c_str()`. Is there a reason you can't use `std::string`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy` doesn't allocate memory for you, you must do it yourself, remembering to leave space for the null termination character:

```
char* url = new char[sup.length()+1];
```

or

```
char url[sup.length()+1];
//...
strcpy(url, sup.c_str());
```

In the first case, don't forget to `delete[]` the array. The second case will only work if your compiler supports C99 variable-length arrays as an extension.

Comment: It may work well but this is not in my opinion the best answer. Do you always rush to accept the first answer that works without waiting to see what others have to say? The reason I don't like this answer is that in C++ you should avoid using new to and raw arrays but should prefer to use vector. boost::shared_array<char> would be another option if you really feel you must use new. The second body I don't particularly like as it picks an arbitary size then hope it fits without any checking whatsoever. In fact I don't know why 32 is picked for the first block either.

Comment: @CashCow Uh no. The answer given is a good one and standard practise in C. Your answer to use boost or vector<char> is unintuitive and (IMO) messy.

Comment: @adelphus: The question is about C++, not C; and even in C it's a very bad idea to use `strcpy` without checking for a potential buffer overrun. Unless you're doing something strange, just use `std::string` when you want a string.

Comment: I guessed I assumed the buffer is enough. You can find the length and allocate as much memory as you need. But in this case he appears to know what the max size of the string will be.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Since `sup` is a `std::string`, you don't need to guess the length. `vector<char>(sup.length()+1)` will give you the array you need, assuming the OP really does need an array for some reason.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'd never use a vector<char> instead of a char*, no matter how much more C++'ish it is.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Why not? It manages the memory for you, and `&v[0]` is exactly the same as a pointer to the first element of any other `char` array. But my main point stands: there's no need to guess the length, and if you insist on managing the memory then use `new char[sup.length()+1];`, with appropriate care to make sure it's deleted.

Comment: @MikeSeymour that's what I said earlier... "You can find the length and allocate as much memory as you need."

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion there are two ways of doing this.

1. **Using &-operator (ampersand)**

   ```
   string str = "hello";
   char *p;
   p = &str[0];
   ```
2. **Using c_str() function**

   ```
   string s = "hello";
   const char *p; 
   p = s.c_str();
   ```

I have tested both and they both are working. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It may work when you test it, but the first one is a bit of a hack and not guaranteed to work.  E.g. if the internal representation of the string was a list of chunks instead of a single block of memory, you wouldn't get the whole string out when you try this.  Hence c_str() exists to force the string to create a single block of memory and zero-terminate it.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` is unsafe as buffer overflow may occur. Use `strncpy` where you're providing exactly number of bytes to copy. You need to allocate memory for the destination buffer and add trailing `\0`:

```
std::string strInsert("news");
std::string sup("http://www.");
sup += strInsert + "yahoo.com";

char* url = new char[sup.length() + 1];
strncpy(url, sup.c_str(), sup.length());
url[sup.length()] = '\0';
// ... use url
delete[] url;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* url = new char[100];
```

You have to allocate memory for your char array first.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a writable buffer of char that is copied from the contents of a std::string, you can use `std::vector<char>`

```
std::vector<char> urlAsVec( sup.begin(), sup.end() );
urlAsVec.push_back( '\0' );
char * url = &urlAsVec[0]; // pointer you can safely write to
```

You can also initialize the vector this way:

```
std::vector<char> urlAsVec( sup.c_str(), sup.c_str() + sup.size() + 1 );
```

which will write your null-terminator for you too.

Another alternative:

```
std::vector<char> urlAsVec( sup.size() + 1 );
sup.copy( &urlAsVec[0], sup.size() );
```

Note that your vector will automatically initialize all its elements to 0 so the null terminator will be there even though sup.copy() doesn't write it. You can use `sup.copy( ptr, len)` instead of strcpy anyway, which is slightly safer in that you can specify the buffer size (although strncpy would allow that too), although you will still have to write the null terminator manually (or have it already allocated).

For example if you use this:

```
char url[ BUFLEN ] = {0};
sup.copy( url, BUFLEN-1 );
```

for some fixed value BUFLEN you will get a copy or partial copy of the source string written into your buffer. Note that my initializer ensures all your unwritten bytes are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Copying from `sup` to `url` doesn't mean you have initialized `url`.
Initializing `url` means allocating memory for it. Like this:

```
url = new char[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string sup = "news";
sup="http://www."+sup+"yahoo.com";
char* url = new char[sup.length()+1];
url = const_cast<char*>(sup.c_str());
url[sup.length()] = '\0';

std::cout<<url;            //http://www.newsyahoo.com
```

Notice the `'\0'` at the end of url.