# C++ string to fixed sized char array possible?

Tags: c++, string, std, cstring

Hi i have the following code:

```
char msg[10000];
string mystr = "hello";
```

I want to put mystr into msg. Is there a way to do that? I tried all sorts of methods, but keep getting:

```
incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*' to char [10000]'
```

I tried:

```
msg = mystr.c_str();
```

and

```
msg = (char[10000])mystr;
```

to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to char * in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309961/how-to-convert-string-to-char-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to copy char * into a string and vice-versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564052/how-to-copy-char-into-a-string-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) for this. Something like:

```
std::copy(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), msg);
```

I would avoid `C` string functions like `mempcy` and `strcpy` in C++.

Comment: Presumably, `msg` should be zero-terminated.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yup, a second step is required if `msg` must be a proper `cstring`.

Comment: Why would you avoid strcpy if it would do the job in one step?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley A gut feeling. But don't take my word, I'm just a beginner in C++.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [string::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/) - it takes a string an puts it into an array.

In your case it would be:

```
std::size_t length = mystr.copy(msg,10000);
msg[length]='\0';
```

Comment: But note that it doesn't zero-terminate the result; if you need that, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: if copy returns 10000 you have a problem

Answer (score 1):

Use copy member function of std::string:

```
size_t len = mystr.copy(msg, (sizeof msg)-1);
msg[len] = 0;
```

Comment: `copy(msg, (sizeof msg)-1)` would avoid a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
char msg[10000];
string mystr = "hello";

strcpy(msg, mystr.c_str());
cout<<msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

String assignment in C is different. You have to copy the bytes into your destination string.

`memcpy_s(msg, 1000, mystr.c_str(), mystr.length()) // safe windows version`

`memcpy(msg, mystr.c_str(), mystr.length()) // unix version`

Comment: This will result in a buffer overflow if the message is longer than 10000 characters, right? It should probably be mystr.length() > 10000 ? 10000 : mystr.length() for the last argument or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use strcpy function :
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/

```
strncpy(msg, mystr.c_str(), sizeof msg / sizeof msg[0]);
msg[sizeof msg / sizeof msg[0] - 1] = 0; // null-terminate in case of truncation
```

Comment: Or `strncpy`, if you don't like buffer overflows.

Comment: sure strncpy would be better.

Comment: To prevent buffer overruns you need to pass the max size of the destination to strncpy, not the size of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers sometimes produce wonky error messages for array types.

Here's an accumulation of previous answers into a paste-and-compile program.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#if 1

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    char msg[1000] = {0};    // initialize to 0 here since we're printing below
                            // the <type> <array-name>[<size>] = {0} just fills a POD struct or an array with 0s

    std::string mystr = "hello";

    // if, at some point, you have things changing "mystr"
    // you'll need to make sure that it will fit in msg[]

    cout << "Before strcpy: \"" << msg << "\"" << endl;

    // I'll just finish the statement in mystr...
    mystr += " world!";

    if(mystr.length() < sizeof(msg)){
        strcpy(
            msg,            // <- put in here until we find a '\0'
            mystr.c_str()    // <- take from here (which could be a temporary buffer)
            );
    }

    //MSC will complain about strcpy being unsafe
    //
    // you can use the below instead (if you really feel the need to), which is
    // the MS-specific equivalent to the above.
    /*
        strcpy_s(
            msg,            // <- put in here until we find a '\0' or the size limit is reached
            sizeof(msg),    // <- don't put any more than this many chars in msg
            mystr.c_str()    // <- take from here
            );
    */

    cout << "After strcpy: \"" << msg << "\"" << endl;

    return 0;
}

#else

// Similarly, using wchar_t (a usually non-byte-sized character type)
//
// note where the divisions occurr

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using std::wcout;
    using std::endl;

    wchar_t msg[1000] = {0};
    std::wstring mystr = L"hello";

    wcout << "Before strcpy: \"" << msg << "\"" << endl;

    mystr += L" world";

    if(mystr.length() < (sizeof(msg)/sizeof(wchar_t))){
        // mystr wil fit!
        wcscpy(
            msg,            // <- put in here until we find a '\0'
            mystr.c_str()    // <- take from here (which could be a temporary buffer)
            );
    }

    // Similar to the char case in the first preprocessor block
    /*
        wcscpy_s(
            msg,                            // <- put in here until we find a '\0' or the size limit is reached
            sizeof(msg)/sizeof(wchar_t),    // <- don't put any more than this many wchar_ts in msg
            mystr.c_str()                    // <- take from here
            );
    */

    wcout << "After strcpy: \"" << msg << "\"" << endl;

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

I shall leave it to you to read the documentation on all related functions.