# Converting from string to char* on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

The method sprintf() is not valid on Arduino. How else can I convert a string to char*?

```
 if(triggerNumber == 4)
 { currenttrack = 5;
 }
  sprintf(trackName, "track%03d.mp3", currenttrack);

  playMP3(trackName); //Go play XX.mp3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7391187/3093378

Comment: This link might help, although it is C++, it has close relationship to Arduino programming: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309961/how-to-convert-string-to-char-in-c)

Comment: In standard C++ `sprintf` is not a *method* (it is not a *member* function). It is just a standard *function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe snprintf will work if you include stdio.h

`snprintf(trackName, sizeof(trackName), "track%03d.mp3", currenttrack);`

Answer (score 1):

There is a String class in Arduino that you can use.
In your case

```
String trackName = "track";
track += currentTrack;
if (currentTrack < 9) {
    track += currentTrack;
}
else {
    track += "0";
    track += currentTrack;
}
track += ".mp3";
playMP3(trackName);
```

There are other String manipulation methods in the String class that may be useful. See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use .c_str().

> Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/